# The volume of the region enclosed by $x=y^3$, $x=0$, $y=2$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

The volume of the region enclosed by $x=y^{3}$, $x=0$, $y=2$, revolved around the X-axis is?

Could I solve it with this integral?

$$\int_1^8 \pi(x^{1/3})dx$$

And another question, how would that solid be represented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the area between $y=x^{\frac13}, x=0, y=2$ revolved around the x-axis, thus, you get $$\pi \int_{0}^{8}[(2)^2-(x^\frac13)^2]\, dx = \pi(32-\frac35(32))=\frac{64\pi}{5}$$

Comment: sry x=y^3 not y^1/3

Comment: Thanks for answering, would not it be from x = 0 to x = 8?

Comment: @Python241820 Thanks for correcting the typo. Just rushed through it. Sorry.